Warum konjugiert man die Vergangenheitsform von "stattfinden" mit "haben"?
Andere Verbe, die dasselbe bedeuten wie "stattfinden", fordern "sein" als Hilfsverb. Das ist passiert, vorgekommen, geschehen, aber das hat stattgefunden. Warum funktioniert "stattfinden" anders?

Zunächst kann man zwei Dinge festhalten (die ein Dilemma ergeben): 1. Es gibt manchmal einen inhaltlichen Faktor, der die Wahl des Hilfsverbs erklärt, zB "sein-Perfekt, wenn ein intransitives Verb einen Zustandswechsel bedeutet". Das zeigt sich eindeutig in den Beispielen "habe geschlafen / bin eingeschlafen". 2. Es gibt manchmal Fälle, wo es nicht an der Bedeutung liegen kann, wie in den Beispielen "habe gestanden / bin gestanden" die ein norddeutsch/süddeutsch-Unterschied sind, aber wohl dasselbe bedeuten.
Mein Eindruck ist, dass es im Deutschen oft Erklärungen gibt, aber dass das "sein-Perfekt" sich zusätzlich auf einige Fälle ausdehnt, wo es willkürlich zu sein scheint, eben bei den Bewegungsverben. Das beantwortet nur nicht die Frage, wie es bei "stattfinden" ist; und hier ist ja das "haben" das Erstaunliche.
Den Hinweis, dass man auf das Verb "finden" schauen soll, finde ich gut. Hier ist zusätzlich zu bedenken, dass "stattfinden" ursprünglich eine transitive Konstruktion gewesen ist, bevor es als 1 Wort aufgefasst wurde: "eine Stätte finden". Das entspricht dem englischen "to take place" . Transitive Konstruktionen können fast nie ein "sein"-Perfekt nehmen.
Zusätzlich kann man fragen, ob es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "stattfinden" gegenüber "passieren, geschehen" gibt. Ich glaub aber eher nicht, weil es auch sonst Parallelen gibt: Zumindest hat man bei allen das Partizip: "die stattgefundenen Kurse" etc (kann man googeln), so wie "die trotzdem passierten / geschehenen Fehler". Das ist nun erstaunlich, weil normalerweise nur ein intransitives Verb mit sein-Perfekt (und transformativer Aktionsart) diese Konstruktionen erlaubt. Das lässt denken, dass es bedeutungsmäßig zu den sein-Perfekt Verben gehören möchte, aber für die Grammatik des "sein-Perfekts" die Transitivität von "finden" dagegen steht.
Sowas Ähnliches hat man ja auch bei reflexiven Verben im Deutschen: "sich öffnen" ist zB ein Verb mit Zustandswechsel, aber haben-Perfekt, und tatsächlich ist es wegen dem "sich" formal eine Konstruktion mit Objekt. Vergleiche: "Es hat sich geöffnet" aber "es ist aufgegangen". Das kann man vermutlich auch nicht aus der Bedeutung erklären.

Danke - aber wolltest du eigentlich sagen, dass normalerweiser nur ein transitives Verb die Konstruktion mit dem Partizip erlaubt? Z. B. "ein begangener Fehler" wäre ein Beispiel der normalen Konstruktion, oder?

Die transitiven sowieso, das gibt dann das  normale "Partizip Passiv", so wie dein Beispiel "einen Fehler begehen" - "ein begangener Fehler". Aber solche Partizipien von intransitiven Verben, das ist eine Auiffälligkeit, und hier gruppiert sich "stattfinden" mit den "sein-Verben", die das typischerweise sonst nur können.

Ach so, danke. Fällst du ein anderes Beispiel von einem solchen Verb ein, wo man nämlich von dessen transformitiv aktionsartiger Intransivität ausgehen würde, dass es "sein" als Hilfsverb nehmen müsste, aber eigentlich (wegen einer transitiven Stammverb oder vielleicht auch nicht) "haben" nimmt? Oder reden wir in "stattfinden" über das einzige?

Die Frage ist ein Spezialfall der allgemeineren Frage, warum bestimmte Verben ihre Perfektform mit "haben" bilden und andere mit "sein".
Üblicherweise bekommt man, wenn man Deutsch lernt, die Auskunft, daß es dafür keine Regel gibt und daß man das einfach auswendig zu lernen hat. Aber, ganz ehrlich: irgendwann muß dieses System ja erfunden worden sein, und zwar von Menschen, die die (damals übliche) Sprache tatsächlich gesprochen haben. Daß deren Motivation war: wir machen das so kompliziert wie nur irgendwie möglich und am besten würfeln wir, welches Modalverb zu welchem Verb paßt, das erscheint jedenfalls kaum glaubhaft.
Tatsächlich gibt es sehr wohl ein System und das ist auch relativ einfach. Hier ist ein Beispiel:

schlafen - ich habe geschlafen
einschlafen - ich bin eingeschlafen
wachen - ich habe gewacht
aufwachen - ich bin aufgewacht

Alle diese Verben haben gemeinsam, daß sie intransitiv sind, aber darüber hinaus verbindet jene, deren Perfekt mit "sein" gebildet wird, noch etwas: der "perfektive Aspekt". Damit ist gemeint: "einschlafen" ist ein Prozeß, der einen natürlichen Anfang und ein natürliches Ende hat: am Anfang ist man wach, am Ende schläft man - dasselbe (nur umgekehrt) mit "aufwachen".
Hingegen haben die Verben "schlafen" oder "wachen" ebendiesen Aspekt nicht: das Schlafen ist ein Zustand, aber dieser Zustand hat kein Ergebnis in dem Sinne, wie das Einschlafen ein Ergebnis - nämlich den Übergang vom Wachen zum Schlafen - hat.
Das ist der Unterschied zwischen den Verben, die "haben" und jenen, die "sein" verwenden.
Dabei gibt es lediglich eine Ausnahme: Verben der Bewegung und alle ihre Ableitungen bilden alle das Perfekt mit "sein", auch wenn sie diesen perfektiven Aspekt nicht haben:

ich bin gegangen
ich bin geritten
ich bin gefahren

Dazu gibt es einige ganz wenige Ausnahmen, die das Perfekt wahlweise mit "haben" oder "sein" bilden und die man dann tatsächlich lernen muß, zB:

ich bin gesessen
ich habe gesessen

Dabei bedeutet ersteres, daß ich in der Vergangenheit irgendwo Platz genommen habe, zweiteres hingegen, daß ich früher einmal im Gefängnis war.

Ich habe gesessen ist norddeutsch (für beide Bedeutungen), ich bin gesessen ist süddeutsch (für die "Platz genommen haben" Bedeutung).

Danke. Diese Antwort stimmt mehr oder weniger mit dem, was mir beigebracht wurde, überein, und genau deshalb habe ich meine Frage gestellt. Vielleicht bin ich müde, aber ich habe deine Antwort mehr als einmal gelesen, und ich suche noch danach, wo oder wie "stattfinden" in sie passt. "Stattfinden" scheint mir, ein gutes Beispiel eines intransitiven Verb mit so einem perfektiven Aspekt zu sein (zumindest genauso wie "passieren"), und man würde also deiner Antwort entnehmen, dass "sein" als Hilfsverb für stattfinden benutzt werden sollte, was aber falsch wäre.

"perfektiver Aspekt" ist aber was anderes. Was du meinst ist eine Bedeutung des Zustandswechsels. Das ist Aktionsart, telische (oder spezieller: transformative) Aktionsart kann man es nennen. Es gibt allerdings atelische Verben mit sein-Perfekt, allen voran "sein".

@Alazon: Zitat aus der Wikipedia: Eigentlich werden unter „perfektive Verben“ aus der Sicht der Einteilung der Aktionsart „terminative Verben“ gekennzeichnet, d. h. ein Geschehen gilt als zeitlich begrenzt und als abgeschlossen. Man kann es also sehr wohl "perfektiver Aspekt" nennen - und man tut das auch.

Welcher WP-Artikel? Und bedeutet die Zitatstelle womöglich: "sogenannte perfektive Verben sollten terminativ heißen"?  Ich weiß, dass Helbig & Buscha für diese Aktionsart-Unterschiede die Bezeichnung "imperfektiv-perfektiv" verwenden, aber ich glaubte, dass dieses Problem heutzutage überwunden wäre. Naja, es gibt die verschiedensten Schulrichtungen und jede hat ihre eigene Sprache. Es bleibt trotzdem eine Verwechslung zwischen zwei Kategorien, auch wenn es häufig ist...

@Alazon: Der Wikipedia-Artikel heißt "Perfektiver Aspekt". Ja, Helbig-Buscha nennen es so, Daniel Scholten (zB in seinem Beitrag über starke Verben) nennt es auch so. Ich sehe das "Problem" nicht, das man "überwinden" müßte. Gib halt einfach einen Downvote und gut ists.

Ah ja, danke. Dort wird diese Ausdrucksweise aber auch als inkorrekt bezeichnet. Aspekt und Aktionsart ist halt nicht dasselbe. Also wenn man etwas unterscheiden kann, versteht man die Dinge schon besser als wenn man sie verwischt.
